# Algolia highlighting in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, algolia

I am using Laravel `5.3` and Algolia,

I want to highlight the search result,I read the documentation but I still don't know how to do it.

https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/php/parameters#attributestohighlight

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

When search results are returned from Algolia, they will wrap the "highlighted part" with `<em> </em>` tags by default. This happens right out of the box, so all you really need to do is use CSS to customize the look of `<em>`s within your search results div to get the effect you want.

Of course if you prefer that they wrap highlighted text in something other than `<em>` then you can customize it with anything you wish (such as maybe a span tag with a "highlighted-search" class or something). You customize this when initializing the search in your PHP.

```
$index = $client->initIndex('contacts');
$result = $index->search('search query', ['attributesToRetrieve' => 'firstname,lastname', 'hitsPerPage' => 50, 'highlightPreTag' => '<span class="highlighted-search">', 'highlightPostTag' => '</span>']);
```

Now let's say you search 'John D' and submit that search query. Algolia will return a string to the effect of:

```
<span class="highlighted-search">John D</span>oe
```

Now with your CSS you customize it like

```
span.highlighted-search {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

and now it will highlight the search query with yellow.

---

Of course this is all assuming you want the static (PHP Library) server side search results. I highly recommend that you use the [autocomplete.js](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js) library so you can get live search results as you type. This requires using the js libraries to return results client-side while the user types. It is a much better experience.

Answer (score 0):

In each item returned by the search engine, there is an extra `"_highlightResult"` attribute that contains some metadata and the value of the searchable attributes modified with search terms surrounded with `<em>`.

For instance, for the search term "toux", the returned JSON will looks like:

```
  {
      "medicament" : "VICKS TOUX SECHE 7,33 mg ADULTES MIEL, pastille",

      "_highlightResult" : {
        "medicament" : {
          "value" : "VICKS <em>TOUX</em> SECHE 7,33 mg ADULTES MIEL, pastille",
          "matchedWords" : ["toux"]
          ....
      ...
  }
```

To highlight the search results, with the search terms, you simply have to display the attribute value under `"_highlightResult"` instead of the raw one.

If you are not using it already, I would recommend you to use [Instantsearch.js](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/).
Highlighting the typed keywords of the search results is dealt whitin the [hits widget](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#hits) the same way, in its `templates.item` parameter.

You may find live code example of this feature here https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/examples/